# Does every normal space have countable basis?

Tags: general-topology

I know that every regular space with a countable basis is normal. But my question is if the converse is true?

---

Normal spaces are obviously regular but does every normal space have a countable basis?

Can someone help me please?

Comment: The [Sorgenfrey line](http://dantopology.wordpress.com/2009/09/27/a-note-on-the-sorgenfrey-line/) is a counterexample.

Comment: *$T_1$* normal spaces are regular.

Comment: @DavidMitra Often, $T_1$ is part of the definition of a normal space (normal is $T_1 \land T_4$). Confusingly, yet others say $T_4$ is normal + $T_1$, and say "normal" is what I know as $T_4$. And for "regular", the same kind of confusion exists.

Comment: @Daniel: It’s unfortunate that the scheme that you learned ever got any traction. I encourage everyone to use the definitions that make the $T_k$ labels into a genuine hierarchy matching the subscripts (e.g., $T_4=\text{normal}+T_1$).

Comment: @Brian I don't know. Having each $T_k$ one single separation axiom has its charm too. I agree that having the $T_k$s being a hierarchy has its merits too. (By the way and off topic: compact = quasicompact & Hausdorff ;)

Comment: @Daniel: Re compact: not a chance! :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the discrete topology on an uncountable set is an obvious counterexample.